# Unexpected difference in behavior seemingly due to using private[this] instead of private

Tags: scala

These two classes behave differently; the cause seems related to the use of a `private[this]` declaration instead of a `private`. Can somebody explain why, please?

- `private`:

  ```
  class Person(
    private var _age: Int
  ) {
    if (_age < 0) { _age = 0 }

    def age = _age
    def age_=(newAge: Int) {
      if (newAge > _age) { _age = newAge }
    }
  }
  ```

  In the REPL, this behaves as I was expecting for both classes; that is, the `age` method gets `_age`, which has been set to the appropriate value during construction:

  ```
  scala> val person = new Person(-1)
  person: Person = Person@200a570f

  scala> person.age
  res0: Int = 0
  ```
- `private[this]`:

  ```
  class Person(
    private[this] var _age: Int
  ) {
    if (_age < 0) { _age = 0 }

    def age = _age
    def age_=(newAge: Int) {
      if (newAge > _age) { _age = newAge }
    }
  }
  ```

  In the REPL, `person.age` appears to take the value of `_age` prior to the evaluation of the `if` expression. It works as expected after using the setter, though:

  ```
  scala> val person = new Person(-1)
  person: Person = Person@6f75e721

  scala> person.age
  res0: Int = -1

  scala> person.age = 0
  person.age: Int = 0

  scala> person.age
  res1: Int = 0
  ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug, namely [SI-6880](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6880).